# Send a string from RFID reader to USB port

Tags: embedded, usb, motorola-emdk

I'm working on Motorola FX7500 RFID reader. I have to send a simple string(or any kind of data) from reader to USB port. I have been searching for the web and the provided resources for hours but I couldn't find anything. If you know how to do this, name of function, a hint or anything would be very useful. Thanks.

Comment: Find out what sort of USB scheme is usually used with that - for example does it pretend to be a keyboard?  In the unlikely event you really need to make something up from scratch, you might use a USB-serial device as a model since your needs may be similar.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It, by default, uses USB as a network connection..

Comment: If you have a connection, it should have an ip address right? So are you able to read any data from the connection?

Comment: I actually managed to read the data from FX7500 reader using vb.net and few libraries

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, a Reader is connected through Ethernet or serial port. You may need to write a daemon (to run on the pc) to keep the connection with the reader and listen for the tag read notify event or gpi event, and then send it to your USB port.

I'm not an expert with motorola, I know impinj and omron devices, but if you need to send the data from a USB port located in the reader, maybe you need to write a script to run in the reader's memory. *For example, in impinj, you can create a script in C/C++ and load it in the reader memory to run at startup.*

I know EMDK is hard to dig for.

Good luck.